# How can I apply a delay to all emissions from my ReplaySubject?

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I want to make a `ReplaySubject` in my Angular app and I want to set it up so that there is always a delay between when an Observer subscribes to it and when it receives an update.

```
let delayedReplay = new ReplaySubject(1);

delayedReplay.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Got:', data);
});

delayedReplay.next('Test');
```

What I want is to apply a delay to the ReplaySubject itself so that the above code would log `'Got: Test'` after, say, 1 second.

Comment: why can't you emit the event after 1 second using setTimeout() function ?

Comment: that's not good practice with rxjs. there is an operator for his use case

Answer (score 5):

You'd have to pipe the `Subject` with `delay` and use the resulting `Observable` for subscribing, while using the original `Subject` for emitting.

It looks like this:

```
let replay = new ReplaySubject(1);

let delayedReplay = replay.pipe(delay(1000));

delayedReplay.subscribe((data) => {
  console.log('Got:', data);
});

replay.next('Test');
```

This should work in all cases, but as stated [in this comment](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/issues/3574#issuecomment-382357300), its also possible to `lift` the subject and cast the result back to a Subject, because `lift` instantiates an `AnonymousSubject`. This may cause some leaky abstraction though as you'd have to know the implemention of Subject to be sure the type cast is valid.

If you want to use it, that solution looks like this:

```
let delayedReplay = <ReplaySubject> new ReplaySubject(1).delay(1000);

// without rxjs-compat in RxJS 6+: 
// let delayedReplay = <ReplaySubject> new ReplaySubject(1).lift(new DelayOperator(1000));

delayedReplay.subscribe((data) => {
    console.log('Got:', data);
});

delayedReplay.next('Test');
```

Note that `lift` may be removed in RxJS 7.

Now, a last option would be to extend ReplaySubject, so you don't have to type cast. Note that this will increase coupling between your implementation and RxJS and neglect the advantanges of composable pipes.

It could look like this:

```
class DelayedReplaySubject<T> extends ReplaySubject<T> {
    constructor(buffer: number, private delay: number) {
        super(delay);
    }

    next(value?: T): void {
        of(value)
            .pipe(delay(this.delay))
            .subscribe(val => super.next(val));
    }
}
```

Comment: Could the same thing be achieved by using a scheduler? I was hoping to keep it as a ReplaySubject type or at least a Subject rather than an Observable, which `pipe` converts it to.

Comment: The `scheduler` would be passed to the operator function as well, so you'd still get an `Observable`. If you use the second approach from my post, you can cast into `ReplaySubject`

Comment: No, the constructor for ReplaySubject allows passing in a scheduler immediately

Comment: You are right, you can also supply it there, but `schedulers` just decide how to process scheduled taskes (like delay), they are not meant to replace the operators. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/doc/scheduler.md

Comment: A third approach would be to extend `ReplaySubject` and overwrite the next method with a delayed observable. I'll add it to my post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that when you subscribe both future and previous items get emitted with delay

```
    this.eventsQueue$ = new ReplaySubject<AnalyticsEvent>();
    this.eventsQueue$.asObservable().pipe(
      concatMap(value => of(value).pipe(delay(2000)))
    ).subscribe((e: AnalyticsEvent) => {
       console.log('event received', e.type);
    });
```